# Why $\mathcal F_\sigma$ and $\mathcal G_\delta$ cannot be replaced by closed and open sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Following is from Bruckner's Analysis book which I could solve all parts but (d) :

[image]

Neither I can produce a counterexample nor I can explain rigorously why $\epsilon \ge 0$ cannot be replaced by $0$.

Please help, thanks! Hints also are very welcome.

Comment: Any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ necessarily has positive measure, so it can never "approximate" a set of $0$ measure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\mathcal F_\sigma$ versus closed, consider what happens for $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n}\right)$. For $\mathcal G_\delta$ versus open consider what happens with $\{1\}$.

Also consider what happens for $E=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1{2n+1},\frac1{2n}\right]$.